# Running Python Function from Bash

Tags: bash, python-3.6

I have created a function configure_propeties() in configure.py that I'm trying to call in a bash script using the following command:

```
python3.6 -c "import configure; print configure.configure_properties()"
```

After executing the the bash script I get the following warning:

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbQNS.png)

Both the script and configure.py are in the same directory. Not sure what's happening it doesn't seem to fail on the import. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: I feel like this must be a duplicate question

Comment: Don't put text in images. Post its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses for `print`, as is necessary for Python 3

Answer (score 1):

`print "blabla"` its only available in python 2, with python 3 you have to use parentheses `print("blabla")`, it would be better to set your python script inside `.py` file, just make sure the python executable is in your PATH environment variable then add in your script

```
python3 path/to/the/python_script.py
```

In the bash script file `bashFile.sh`, put this :

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 path/to/the/python_script.py
```

then you can execute your bash file `bashFile.sh` :

```
bash path/to/bashFile.sh
```